# Pass data through levels - open Modal dialog at the end

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've been pounding my head on this for many hours and could use some help.

Fundamentally, what I am trying to do is that I have two layers of components - the last of which is supposed to open up a Modal Dialog when you click it.  Because of React's idea that a component should only change its own state, I want to propagate that data up and set that variable.

Here is the layout.  The `FirstLevel.jsx` file is the top of my hierarchy.  It is followed by `SecondLevel.jsx` and `ThirdLevel.jsx` which is where the actual text is clicked.

I don't know about the syntax on anything.  Not sure if `onUserInput` is the right attribute to use or `handleUserClick` is a built-in thing or a user-defined thing.  The idea here is that I am trying to propagate the callback function `handleUserClick` down into the `SecondLevel`.  Is this right so far?

**FirstLevel.jsx**

```
export default class FirstLevel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dialogActive: ''
        };
        this.handleUserClick = this.handleUserClick.bind(this);
    }

handleUserClick(dialogActive) {
    this.setState({
        dialogActive: dialogActive
    });
}

render() {
    <SecondLevel onUserInput={this.handleUserClick}/>
}
```

Now, on the `SecondLevel`, I propagate the callback function even further down into the `ThirdLevel`.  Is this the right way to do it so far?

**SecondLevel.jsx**

```
render () {
    //other logic and tags before this

    <ThirdLevel onUserInput={this.props.onUserInput}/>
}
```

Now this level is where all hell breaks loose and I have no idea what I am doing.  On the click, I want to set the `dialogActive` variable that was propagated down and then let that float back up.  I still don't know if `onUserInput` is the right thing to do or if the parameter is even correct.  Everything is very hazy because it was just gotten by following tutorials and doing lots of Googling and throwing in bits and pieces from everywhere.

**ThirdLevel.jsx**

```
export default class ThirdLevel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {

        this.props.onUserInput(
            this.dialogActive.value
        );

        //show Modal dialog somehow
    }

    render() {

        return <text ref={(input) => this.dialogActive = true} onClick={this.handleClick}> {this.props.value}</text>;
    }
```

Finally, I want to show some modal dialog.  Clicking the text needs to reveal a modal dialog. The modal dialog is in another component called `MyModal.jsx`

In the `ThirdLevel`, I've tried importing `MyModal` and tried calling the `showModal` function.  Didn't work.  Then, I tried doing some `React.createElement(MyModal)` stuff and rendering it but that didn't work.  All kind of other things that I forgot and just trying stuff until it works but it didn't.  What am I doing wrong?

**MyModal.jsx**

```
export default class MyModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};

        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);

    }

    showModal() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    render() {

        return (
                <Modal
                    {...this.props}
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onHide={this.hideModal}
                    dialogClassName={styles.largeDialogBox}
                >
                //more modal stuff here
           );
     }
}
```

Big picture: trying to propagate a click action back up to the top of the hierarchy to set some state and that click action needs to open a modal dialog.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Do I do something like this in my `ThirdLevel`?

```
handleClick() {

    this.props.onUserInput(
        this.dialogActive.value
    );

    //show Modal dialog somehow
    var newmodal = new MyModal(this.props);
    React.render(React.createElement(newModal));
}

render() {
    return <text onClick={this.handleClick}> {this.props.value}</text>;
}
```

**Edit 2**

My `ThirdLevel` render function returns this:

```
<div>
    <MyModal isDialogActive={this.props.dialogActive} onHideModal={this.props.onUserInput}/>
    <tspan onClick={this.handleClick}> {this.props.value} </tspan>
</div>
```

When that gets passed back up into the `SecondLevel`, it becomes:

```
<text>
    <div>
        <MyModal isDialogActive={this.props.dialogActive} onHideModal={this.props.onUserInput}/>
        <tspan onClick={this.handleClick}> {this.props.value} </tspan>
    </div>
</text>
```

It's weird to wrap things in the `div` but that's the only way to make the render work.  Even though the resulting DOM has all the tags there, none of the actual `tspan`s are showing.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the handling of showing / hiding the modal to be set in the state of what you called `FirstLevel`?

Comment: hey @noblerare since we resolved this via email you should come back here and update it in case other people stumble across it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will get you on the right path.

I would suggest refactoring the name of some of your functions as it does get a bit confusing. `handleUserClick` then `onUserInput` etc. But you've already mentioned that in your OP.

```js
// First Level
export default class FirstLevel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dialogActive: false
        };
        this.handleUserClick = this.handleUserClick.bind(this);
    }

  handleUserClick(dialogActive) {
      this.setState({
          dialogActive: dialogActive
      });
  }

  render() {
      <SecondLevel onUserInput={this.handleUserClick}/>
  }
}

// Second Level
...
render () {
    //other logic and tags before this
    <ThirdLevel onUserInput={this.props.onUserInput}/>
}
...

// Third Level
export default class ThirdLevel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
      this.props.onUserInput(true);
    }

    render() {

        return (
          <div>
            <MyModal isDialogActive={this.props.dialogActive} onHideModal={this.props.onUserInput} />
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Show Modal</button>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

// Modal
export default class MyModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    }

    hideModal() {
      this.props.onUserInput(false);
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <Modal
                    {...this.props}
                    show={this.props.isDialogActive}
                    onHide={this.hideModal}
                    dialogClassName={styles.largeDialogBox}
                >
                //more modal stuff here
           );
     }
}
```

However I would be asking why you need this logic in the `FirstLevel` and it cannot be further down the component tree.

Comment: thanks this is a great help.  However, one issue that I am having is at the `render` function on the `ThirdLevel`.  I understand that you have to return some parent tag but in my case this doesn't work for me.  The parent tag on the `SecondLevel` is a `text` tag and therefore, if I wrap its children in a `div`, none of the labels are generated. In other words, it's like having a `table` tag and all of its rows are wrapped in `div`s

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: With the way I structured it the Modal should be showing when the `dialogActive` prop is set to true. Are you using a particular lib for your modal?

Comment: Yea, I'm using the Modal from `react-bootstrap`  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals

Comment: Yeah so if you follow how they've structured their "basic example" then as per my code sample you have the button in `ThirdLevel` set the dialogtoactive which will cause a re-render and propogate down the `isDialogActive` to the `MyModal` component.

Comment: I just realised that I had `Modal` in the `ThirdLevel` render. It should be `MyModal` based on your example. Updated now.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept your question because I believe that it is the correct way to do it but it's not working for me.  I restructured my code in the way that you explained but it's not working because of the `<div>` wrapper on the `ThirdLevel`.  I'll explain in an edit in my post.

Comment: It's almost certainly because you're trying to put a div inside a text. happy to discuss outside of SO - pgord1 at gmail dot com